# How to open a specific app in my app？

Tags: ios, url-scheme

I know that i can use url scheme.
But if there are some other app also register the same scheme, then the action will be undefined.
Does some one have ideas to do with it?

Answer (score 0):

Your URL scheme for this purpose must be unique. If you an another app share a URL scheme, one of you should change. The namespace is big enough that there is no reason for collisions.

Comment: That you for your replay!I am afraid that some other app for some reason get my scheme and use the same scheme.But I can not stop them to use.So I want to know whether there are some method to deal with this problem.

Comment: I thought my answer was clear about that. There is no method to deal with that problem. I'll add that if you're the small company making a small app, just give in and change your scheme.